# How to draw the interactions between source and destination countries using ip address?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to create a clickable world map with one marker for each country. When a marker of a source country is being clicked, interactions should be shown with other countries in a aggregated way. I was able to draw the world map but I am not sure about how to draw the interactions between 2 countries using ip addresses which are given in the CSV files. I tried looking for solutions but in vain. I am new to d3.js. Would be great if someone could throw some light into this.

A suggestion would be of really helpful. suggestion about how to go forward using any relative library(if needed) or any other suggestion would be as helpful as any direct answers. Thank you.
Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/WuNUgMZdD1ztfoij2TeX?p=preview)

**Here is the Script**

```
var app = angular.module("chartApp", []);
app.controller("SalesController", function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("countries.csv").then(function(response) {
    $scope.salesData = response;
    });
});

app.directive("linearChart", function($window) {
return {
    restrict: "EA",
    // template: "<svg width='1024' height='728'></svg>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // canvas resolution
        var margin = { top: 50, left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50 },
            height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right;

        // defines "svg" as data type and "make canvas" command
        var svg = d3.select("#map")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // var width = 1500,
        //     height = 900;

        d3.queue()
            .defer(d3.json, "https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.json")
            .defer(d3.csv, "countries.csv")
            .await(ready);

        // projection-settings for mercator    
        var projection = d3.geoMercator()
            // .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
            // where to center the map in degrees
            .center([-30, 60])
            // // zoomlevel
            .scale(200);
        // // map-rotation
        // .rotate([0, 0]);

        /* Create a Path using projection */

        var path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);


        function ready(error, data, country_name) {
            console.log(data);


            var countries = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.countries).features;
            console.log(countries);
            console.log(country_name);

            /* Add a path for each country
                 Shapes -> Path
            */

            svg.selectAll(".country")
                .data(countries)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "country")
                .attr("d", path)
                .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                    d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                    d3.select(this).classed("selected", false);
                });

            svg.selectAll(".country-circles")
                .data(country_name)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "circle")
                .attr("r", 2)
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    var coords = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]);
                    return coords[0];
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    var coords = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]);
                    return coords[1];
                });

            svg.selectAll(".countries")
                .data(country_name)
                .enter().append("marker")
                .attr("class", "countries")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    var coords = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]);
                    return coords[0];
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    var coords = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]);
                    return coords[1];
                })

                // .text(function(d) {
                //     return d.country_name;
                // })
                .attr("dx", 5)
                .attr("dy", 2);
           }
         }
      };
  });
```

Comment: Data from an $http request is `response.data`. This would be obvious if you looked at the `response` object with `console.log`. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Hey thank you. But $http request data is used after the map is displayed but the map is not getting displayed here at first

Comment: Where did you get this code? Every line seems to be broken. The directive is not being instantiated because its name is not properly normalized. The postLink code looks for an element with the `id="map"` but there is no such element. The list goes on.

Comment: do you have country to ip address mapping ?

Comment: No, source country ip address to destination country ip addresses mapping.

Comment: @HebleV What kind of interactions are you trying to show? Something like a line connecting two points or a series of lines between different countries maybe? A visual mock and some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: I want to display interaction like ookla test where I could see interactions between source country and destination countries. Here is the plnkr which also has sample data. https://plnkr.co/edit/WuNUgMZdD1ztfoij2TeX?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

To point you in the right direction:

You have a CSV file with IP addresses, but in my opinion, you need the longitude and latitude of the countries.

You could try to batch convert these [here](http://www.freegeocoding.com/) or maybe you could use an api like [this](http://ip-api.com/docs/) in order to get the right long and lat with the corresponding IP addresses.

In order to show the interaction between those points, I think this example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/erikhazzard/6201948) is most helpfull to get you on your way.

Comment: I do have lat and long values as well. you can see in the plnkr i provided

Comment: Aha! There they are, hiding in plain sight! Well, i hope you can solve your issue based on the given example